# JQuery - Select image by alt or title

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, image, alt

Hello I need this JQuery to run for the image bellow it. But here's the trick I need to select the image by it's alt, I can't seem to get the JQuery to select it

```
<script>                                    
 $('img[alt="800px-Red_Bull"]').onload = function() {
 Pixastic.process(img, "desaturate", {average : false});
</script>

<img width="800" height="387" src=".../01/800px-Red_Bull.png" alt="800px-Red_Bull" title="800px-Red_Bull">
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you need to call `load` and not `onload`. The selector code looks good.

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Kdecq/).

Comment: Note that `.../` is not a valid path. `./` is the current directory, `../` is the parent directory. `.../` does not exist.

Answer (score 17):

Your problem is not with your selector, it's that you're not using the `load` event correctly.

Change your code to this:

```
$('img[alt="800px-Red_Bull"]').load(function() {
    Pixastic.process(img, "desaturate", {average : false});
});
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to work, I uploaded it to jsfiddle, can you take a look?
http://jsfiddle.net/donvito101/prLtF/1/

Comment: @ThomasDepole - there are a bunch of things wrong with that fiddle. First, you never loaded jQuery. Second, you didn't load pixastic so that won't work either. Third you had jsfiddle set to `load` which will occur after this event. Also, as I recall you can't do inline jQuery declarations on jsFiddle (someone correct me if im wrong). Instead you have to set it to use `onready`. See that this works - http://jsfiddle.net/prLtF/2/

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('img[alt="800px-Red_Bull"]').load(function () {
 Pixastic.process(img, "desaturate", {average : false});
});
```